# always duplicate notification GCM after update new version app android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

i get issue gcm notification. I get always duplicate(2,3,4) notification GCM after once update new version app android from eclipse. Where in the server, id gcm just one registered,  how to fix it ? sorry for my english

Comment: Are you sure your server doesn't get a new registration ID when the app's version is updated? If your server doesn't handle changes in registration IDs correctly, you might have multiple registration IDs for the same device, which will explain the duplicated messages.

Comment: yes, in my server just one id gcm, how to clear  multiple registration IDs for the same device ?

Comment: add unregister mechanism for the device?

Answer (score 3):

the solution of this issue is sending a unique ID for each device (likes : Device ID in android), and making it a primary key 
so any update of the token for this unique id it will be updated instead of adding new one